# PHP - Showing data in array

Tags: php, jquery

The following code is referenced in an autocomplete object I have on my page

```
<?php
require('json.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("timetable") or die("No such database");
$sql = sprintf("SELECT id,dsc FROM module WHERE dsc LIKE '%%%s%%'",
               mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']));
$result = mysql_query($sql)
  or die(mysql_error());
$all = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $all[] = array('value'=>$row[1],'label'=>$row[1]);
print json_encode($all);
?>
```

The autocomplete is working fine but there is no option to then display the data. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: There is none at all, once I select the module and hit enter, nothing

Comment: How is this code connected to the client side?

Comment: Do you mean how is the autocomplete connect to the php script. If so

Comment: $(function(){
  $('#who').autocomplete({
    source:'scripts/searchstaff.php'
  });
});

Comment: you should you use print. It should return only Right?

Comment: There is a print in the code already

Comment: Do you check with firebug console. whether the php code is excuted or not

Comment: It must be as it find the module in autocomplete, it just doesn't let me display the data

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this? it may helps you

```
 <?php
    require('json.php');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or
        die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("timetable") or die("No such database");
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT id,dsc FROM module WHERE dsc LIKE '%%%s%%'",
                   mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']));
    $result = mysql_query($sql)
      or die(mysql_error());
    $all = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    array_push($all,array('value'=>$row[1],'label'=>$row[1]));
    }
    echo(json_encode($all));
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('#who').autocomplete({
    source: function() {
      $.get('scripts/searchstaff.php', function(data) {
        $(target).text(data);
        return data;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Autocomplete uses the echo/return from your php just internally for itself, you have to catch the data and write it out clientside.

Note: data would be a json string, you can parse it into an object with `JSON.parse(data)`, then do whatever you want with the object.